# Unity Application crashed on adreno based graphics card

Tags: unity-game-engine

I just got Fatal Exception on LG-G2-D802 Device. Unity version is 5.3.5f1.

What causes `libGLESv2_adreno.neon_pld_min_max_16 (neon_pld_min_max_16:5)` fatal error ?

```
java.lang.Error
libGLESv2_adreno.neon_pld_min_max_16 (neon_pld_min_max_16:5)
libGLESv2_adreno.cache_vertex_elements (cache_vertex_elements:80)
libGLESv2_adreno.core_glDrawElementsInstancedXXX (core_glDrawElementsInstancedXXX:324)
libGLESv2_adreno.core_glDrawElements (core_glDrawElements:10)
libGLESv2_adreno.glDrawElements (glDrawElements:28)
libunity.004ac2b0 (Unknown Source)
libunity.0011fb94 (Unknown Source)
libunity.00170f68 (Unknown Source)
libunity.001721dc (Unknown Source)
libunity.001761f0 (Unknown Source)
libunity.0010fdc0 (Unknown Source)
libunity.00112648 (Unknown Source)
libunity.0012d6d0 (Unknown Source)
libunity.00389768 (Unknown Source)
libunity.0038ab04 (Unknown Source)
libunity.004d7260 (Unknown Source)
libunity.004dc710 (Unknown Source)
data@app@com.00627e4b (Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Do you have selected  the "Dynamic Batching" option in Unity's "Player Settings?